# Issue with changed gravatar icon. Changed after asking a question

Tags: support, gravatar, email, hash

My gr-avatar changed. Read that it was a hash of email address. However it's the same as last time. Is the hashing case sensitive?

e.g.
SomeEmail@SomeDomain.com is different from someemail@somedomain.com

I did not hate my old icon. The new one really blows. So now I miss it.

EDIT: Verified case is irrelevant

EDIT: Logged into SO this morning and I have the old gr-avatar, issue gone but not resolved.

EDIT: If you have not provided an email in your profile the gr-avatar is assigned by the IP that you use when you sign in. You can change your gr-avatar fooling with the value of the email at the expense of notification.

Comment: It can change after an IP address change if you don't have an email address added to your profile. And yes, I believe the algorithm is case sensitive, so you would have a different gravatar if your address was Abc@d.com instead of abc@d.com.

Comment: @alex, the hash indeed *is* case sensitive, but that is why websites always calculate the hash of the lowercased email address. (That is: they *should* lowercase it, if using Gravatar correctly.)

Comment: Are you saying I can get a new icon for different forms of character entropy that I put in the email filed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a stable gravatar, provide a stable email address in your profile.

Otherwise, as alex noted (should have been an answer IMO) it is based on IP address in the absence of an email address.

Comment: there is no email in address in my profile. I just use the options for OAuth.

Comment: @Smith325, if you did *not* set up any email, then where did you test that the case is irrelevant? The OpenID details are not used. So, when there's no email address in your profile, then all is based on your IP address, like both alex and Jeff stated.

Comment: So then, what your saying is that the image is based on where i authenticate from.

Answer (score 0):

The hash you send to Gravatar must be trimmed and lower-case, for those who arrive here via s search engine. Linky: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/